# Limit the number of rows and columns in datalist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

As stated above, is that possible to make one in code behind. And how do you retrieve it from the database? I did see websites for details but it was kind of confusing. Is there any simpler ways to do that too? 
Thanks

Ok. Sorry but this is my code

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            UpdateDatabind()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub UpdateDatabind()
        Dim Product As New Product
        Dim dataset As New DataSet
        Dim count As Integer
        Dim Pds As New PagedDataSource
        dataset = Product.GetProduct()
        If dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            'For paging 
            Pds.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
            Pds.AllowPaging = True
            Pds.PageSize = 1
            Pds.CurrentPageIndex = 0
            Session("Pds") = Pds            
            'Bind the datalist
            dlProducts.DataSource = dataset
            dlProducts.DataBind()
            count = dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count
            lblCount.Text = "Total records:" & count
            lbl1.Text = "Showing Page: " & Pds.CurrentPageIndex.ToString() & " of " & Pds.PageCount.ToString()
        Else
            lblCount.Text = "No records is found"
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub dlProducts_UpdateCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListCommandEventArgs) Handles dlProducts.UpdateCommand
        dlProducts.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrevNext_Command(source As Object, e As CommandEventArgs)
        ' Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath
        Dim pds As PagedDataSource = Session("pds")
        Dim CurrentPage As Integer
        If Not CurrentPage = 0 Or CurrentPage < pds.PageCount Then
            CurrentPage = pds.CurrentPageIndex
            If e.CommandName = "Next" Then
                CurrentPage += 1
                Response.Redirect("~/Products.aspx?PageIndex=" & CurrentPage)
            ElseIf e.CommandName = "Previous" Then
                CurrentPage -= 1
                Response.Redirect("~/Products.aspx?PageIndex=" & CurrentPage)
            End If
        Else
            If pds.IsFirstPage Then
                lbPrev.Visible = False
                lbPrev1.Visible = False
            End If
            If pds.IsLastPage Then
                lbNext.Visible = False
                lbNext1.Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I can get the results in datalist but I do not seem to limit the rows and columns. Example I want to retrieve 3x3 datalist.

Comment: You need to expand this question a LOT.

Comment: please post part of your code or can you try to rephrase your question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks for info. I have edited my question abit. hope it is understandable.. :X